# How to count specific file in a zip file

Tags: java, zip

I have zip file that contains many zip entries 
(many png images).

I want to count the number of images that contains word `"idle"`

The zip entries are like this:

on001,on002...on0037-idle001,idle002...idle0085

Please tell me how to count number of files that their name contains word `"idle"`

I know how to count all file in zip by `.size()` but how do I count specific ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the `.entries()` and check each `ZipEntry`s name:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("???.zip");

int count = 0;

Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
    if (entry.getName().contains("idle")) count++;
}
```

Comment: nice but i got error

foreach not applicable to type 'java.util.enumeration<capture<? extends java.util.zip.zipEntry

Comment: by the way i found another way but its too slow and lagy.. can u tell the reason plz

Comment: If I was to guess, I would say that it's possible this method is just using a table of contents at the start of the zip file, and your method is actually seeking to the start of each zip file entry, which is OK if you are actually opening them but more work if you're not.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem by this code but its too slow weston's code is much better

```
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("zip file adress");
            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis);
            ZipEntry ze = null;


            int idlecount;
            while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null){
                if (ze.getName().contains("idle")){
                    idlecount++;
                }

            }
```